# Annotation title not appearing when adding viewForAnnotation

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mkmapview

I have added this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "id")

    if let title = annotation.title{
        if title! == "P"{
            pinView.pinTintColor = UIColor.yellow
        }
        else{
            pinView.pinTintColor = UIColor.gray
        }
    }
    return pinView
}
```

But when I do this I can´t see my titles when I click on an annotation anymore, any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `canShowCallout` on your `pinView`. If the value of the `canShowCallout` property is `true`, a standard callout bubble is shown when the user taps a selected annotation view. The callout uses the title and subtitle text from the associated annotation object.

So just add the following row to your `viewFor` function and you´ll see the title.

```
pinView.canShowCallout = true
```